# Cannot allocate memory

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, ubuntu

```
EXCEPTION: 11DbException
Db::get: Cannot allocate memory
bitcoin in ProcessMessage()
```

Downloaded 250k blocks, now it won't run anymore i'm running ubuntu 12.04, I have 20GB HD and 1gb ram. any way to fix without redownloading?

Comment: You have 20GB ram free or just 20GB ram with the operating system on it plus all your other data?

Comment: Oops mistyped that, I meant hard-drive of course.

Answer (score 1):

bitcoind uses a ton of memory while it's downloading the blockchain. Check out these steps on how to set up your swap space correctly on Ubuntu:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Additionally, you can check out the torrent download of the blockchain. As long as you trust the file, this can help speed up the time to download the blockchain.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/bootstrap.dat.torrent/download